# Unit Testing (e.g.Specflow) vs Selenium

Tags: java, eclipse, unit-testing, selenium, webdriver

I'm currently learning about how to run automation tests through Selenium. Further on down the line, I'd also like to look at how Unit Testing works (through Specflow, Cucumber etc). My question is......in an ideal world, would both unit testing and GUI testing through Selenium be required? Or if I have unit tests build, for example, through Visual Studio, does this mean I no longer need to build any test scripts in Selenium?

Hopefully someone can help my understanding of this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This would deeply depend on the whole development lifecycle approach.

In an ideal world, developers write unit tests. But someone else needs to test their work (2nd pair of eyes). So a tester would also write tests (whether automated or manual test scripts).

Cucumber & TestNG basically work like Unit Tests do, Cucumber specifically is normally invoked by junit. So the danger you have, is that a developer and a tester may both cover the exact same code. But that in itself is the ideal situation from a developement lifecycle point of view. From a business point of view, it's not.

The cross over from Unit Test to "junit invoked Cucumber running a Selenium test" is a grey area. Personally, if you were to stick to a Selenium WebDriver I think you'd be OK, because you'd be testing from an end user perspective. Whereas if you use Selenium WebClient, then you're running the risk of missing bugs that a user may see.

Comment: That's great, thank-you Dave. The development team here have asked the question about introducing specflow, so I was just ensuring that by continuing down the road with my Selenium tests these won't be obscolete when/if more involved unit testing is introduced. From what you're saying, it sounds like the two should be separated out, in that unit testing is done by the developers with no involvement from test.....in terms of the GUI testing, I can continue with doing this in Selenium. Would I be correct there?

Comment: That'd be a decision for the development manager, basically. There's a danger of cross over, and basically wasting a little time/money, but so long as it's managed carefully, I can't really see there being a big issue. For a little background, I write Selenium/Cucumber frameworks for my employer, so that testers can use a common in-house API without worrying about the underlying Java. I hadn't seen Specflow before, but 2mins of searching tells me it's basically just "Cucumber-JVM for .NET" - so no different to what I already use.

Comment: Brilliant, thanks Dave. That's answered my question

Comment: No worries, have fun with the many quirks of WebDriver (especially if you need Chrome)! I've just seen some of your other questions, so will have a thumb through, see if there's anything else I can steer you on. :-)

Comment: Cheers Dave. The previous one I asked today hasn't been answered so if you have any ideas on that it would be appreciated